# No nine-thousand computer has ever made a mistake or distorted information

Tags: grammaticality

HAL¹ used this sentence in the 1968 classic film *'2001: A Space Odyssey'* when interviewed from Earth by Amor. HAL had ~seven minutes to compose a response.

> HAL: Let me put it this way, Mr. Amor. The nine-thousand series is the most reliable computer ever made. **No nine-thousand computer has ever made a mistake or distorted information**. We are all, by any practical definition of the words, foolproof and incapable of error.
>  <sub>*source:* [Transcript of the Film 2001 A Space Odyssey](http://miscel.wikidot.com/2001-transcript)</sub>

Should it be grammatically correct to use *nor* in place of *or* here or was HAL correct all along?

> No nine-thousand computer has ever made a mistake **nor** distorted information ...

---

¹ <sub>The HAL 9000 was a Heuristically Programmed ALgorithmic Computer. There are many speculations that the name HAL originated from a one letter shift off IBM.</sub>

Comment: For once I think HAL is right.

Comment: FWIW, I fear I'm wrong simply due to Kubrick's strict attention to detail but I wouldn't mind an outside ruling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No nine-thousand computer has ever [[made a mistake] or [distorted
>   information]].

There's essentially no way that the sentence can be parsed differently.

If it were:

> A nine-thousand computer has never made a mistake nor distorted
>   information.

then that would be different.

Comment: Thank you for a definitive answer.